# Restful API: Is it meaningful to send PUT without enclosed entity?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following scenario:

There are two existing entity: `shopping card #1` and `item #1`. I want to add `item #1` to `shopping card #1`. There are two possible ways to design a `Restful api`:

**1:**
Without body:

```
PUT http://myshoppingsite.com/api/shoppingcards/1/items/1
Host: myshoppingsite.com
```

**2:** With body (having enclosed-entity):

```
PUT http://myshoppingsite.com/api/shoppingcards/1/items/
Host: myshoppingsite.com    

{itemId: "1"}
```

Actually, I cannot decide which one is better and is more meaningful in terms of restfulness. Any idea?

(**Note**: I believe the http method should be `PUT` because of idempotency, but this is not my question here.)

**PS:** The problem I have with the first design is that there is no such `enclosed entity` in the request. Linguistically put is a transitive verb, so I expect somebody `put`s **something** somewhere. I think the same story somehow is in the HTTP world.

Comment: In your scenario #2 is definitely wrong because the `PUT` here would have to replace everything in the `items` collection.

Comment: @Evert I don't think so. It depends on how to handle the request in back-end

Comment: Yes you can handle it in a way where it doesn't do that, but that _is_ the definition of the `PUT` method as per HTTP. If you _don't_ do that you're most certainly not doing it right. Don't call it RESTful (or HTTP) then.

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure if I understand it correctly or not but here (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) under `PUT` section it reads *HTTP/1.1 does not define how a PUT method affects the state of an origin server*

Comment: @Evert  Would you please take a look at update?

Comment: You're reading an outdated rfc. First sentence here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4

Comment: But this is not new since the new rfc. Even the old one absolutely implies this. If you try to find any other expert source on the web, I guarantee that they will confirm this. Furthermore a PUT request that replaces the resource is pretty much a requirement to for the REST philosophy.

Comment: @Evert Ok no matter what PUT should do, do you feel ok with a PUT request with no enclosed entity in the paylod or body?

Comment: A `PUT` request with no enclosed entity implies to me that you are replacing the target resource with an empty representation. It's definitely a bit weird. The URL should be meaningless, so the fact that you put special meaning to the fact that the URL contains an id is imho wrong.

Comment: @Evert But in your first comment you said that the second solution is wrong

Comment: I think the main issue is that you are creating an empty resource, which should be meaningless. Is this a real API you are developing? I assume that when you add something to a cart, there should be *some* information about the product you are adding, no?

Comment: And if if you treat the id in the url as the product id, this basically goes against restful principles. I would disconnect the id your shopping cart url from your product ids. In fact: you should completely ditch id's if you can. I'll add an answer to elaborate.

Comment: @Evert Why do you think "treating the id in the url as the product id" basically goes against restful principles ?

Comment: @Evert *there should be some information about the product you are adding, no?* Yes and that information is part of Uril. Why is it bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PUT` is a HTTP verb that is supposed to create or replace the target URI, so this makes your first option immediately wrong. This request *should* replace *all* the items in your shopping cart:

```
PUT http://myshoppingsite.com/api/shoppingcards/1/items/
```

Since you want to *add* something to your shopping cart, this is not an option. This leaves effectively two options. First: the common one:

```
POST http://myshoppingsite.com/api/shoppingcards/1/items/
```

`POST` can mean many things, but in the context of REST services it's often used to append something to a collection. However, you mention that you want idempotence. You have two options here, first you *can* still use `POST` and within the context of your API guarantee that the request *will* be idempotent. Using `POST` does not mean that it's per definition non-idempotent, it just means that the HTTP spec alone does not guarantee it. That does not prevent *you* from making the request idempotent.

The other option is indeed `PUT`:

```
PUT http://myshoppingsite.com/api/shoppingcards/1/items/1
```

Your have a concern with that though, because in the context of your API you say that the request body would end up empty.

The reason for this is that you attach special to the last `/1` in the url, and I think this what's wrong. If you want to follow REST best practices, then urls should not have any special meaning.

I think a saner way to do this, if you insist on using `PUT` is to get rid of the notion of "an id". That concept only exists in your database and should not make its way to the API.

Instead, I imagine that your service has a list of products such as this one:

```
http://myshoppingsite.com/products/1
```

To add a product to a shopping cart using `PUT`, this request might look something like this:

```
PUT http://myshoppingsite/api/shoppingcards/1/items/[completely-arbitrary-string-or-perhaps-a-uuid]
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "product" : "http://myshoppingsite.com/products/1",
   "quantity" : 5
}
```

Personally, I would just use `POST` though.

**Q: there should be some information about the product you are addisng, no? Yes and that information is part of Uril. Why is it bad?**

I'm not saying it's bad, I'm saying it's not RESTful. Pick up any book about REST and you will see this confirmed. This might also be a good place to start reading more about what REST is:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

I would personally say that very little people build true RESTful services. This is why I also want to specifically point out that I don't want to say this is bad or good for your specific API, it's simply not RESTful.

**What if I don't care about these principles and want to keep my special-meaning url scheme?**

Well that's a fair point, but then we've gone beyond the original question here. If you want to design an API where the last bit of the url is actually the 'representation' of the item in your shopping cart, then yes I agree that having it *also* in the body is redundant.

In that situation I'd say, keep the request body empty. Just don't call it REST I guess.

Comment: In that reference, Martin Fowler says: *But I do want to point out that some people incorrectly make a correspondence between POST/PUT and create/update.*. Don't you think it's against your very first sentence?

Comment: No it does not. He means to say that people commonly think `POST` = create and `PUT` = update. As I've explained here, you can use `PUT` to create new resources as well.

Comment: I will stop commenting here though. I came here to answer your question based on my experience, not to have an argument. You clearly don't like the answer I'm giving you. If you are interested, do more research and you'll see that the experts tend to agree with what I'm saying.

Comment: For what it's worth I've also gone through the process some time ago to learn exactly what REST is and really means, and came to the conclusion that following all the principles for building REST services is *probably* not a good idea for most real-world products, and kind of annoying to implement.

Comment: First, I highly appreciate your collaboration. Second, argument is part of learning. While I respect your experience and ideas, I just don't want to blindly follow anything. Third, I still don't understand why having id in Uri is against `Restfulness` :D

Comment: It's not that having the id there is bad, it's the fact that clients need to manually assemble the url based on a shopping cart, and an id from the product you are adding. Besides, you are not adding an id, you are adding a product? How do you identify this product? With a url! This is why I introduced a separate 'products' api endpoint for your real products.

Comment: Why is it not restful? there's a bunch of reasons. An important reason is that the real content (representation) of your data is no longer in your bodies. REST is about defining media types. What's yours?

Comment: I agree that argument is a good way to learn, but maybe not appropriate for stack overflow. Also, it's taking up quite a bit of my time ;)

Comment: After pondering on your explanations and doing some research, I finally found what was the wrong with my design: I coupled client to server via some unwritten communication protocol hence making the client to build the url based on that protocol. Thank you very very much.